# Out of memory java heap spcae with MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, heap-memory

I'm getting the above error when trying retrieve some data from a MySQL statement, as the error states the error is in line 118; here is the MySQL:

```
                    .prepareStatement("SELECT orderr.* FROM orderr JOIN person ON orderr.personID = person.personID WHERE person.first_name = ?",java.sql.ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, java.sql.ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY, Integer.MIN_VALUE);
```

Code near line 118:

```
            int index = 0;
        if (rs.next()) {
            index++;
            rs.beforeFirst();
            while (rs.next()) {
                for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++) { // retrive column data from order
                    message.append(rs.getInt(i));   //table and append to sb.
                    if(i != 3)message.append(" "); <---line 118.
                }
                if(rs.next()){
                    rs.absolute(index);
                    message.append("\n");
                }
            }
        }
```

The exact error I get is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2367)
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.expandCapacity(AbstractStringBuilder.java:130)
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(AbstractStringBuilder.java:114)
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:415)
at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:237)
at stl.Sql.printPersonsOrders(Sql.java:118)
at stl.Main.main(Main.java:19)
```

This error only occurs when I have added the same data twice to the table and then try and retrieve, the amount of data should only be one or two rows.

Comment: How many rows does your SELECT return?

Comment: what error do you get ?

Comment: Have you run the query from a db tool to show that only 2 rows are returned? How are you starting Java, i.e. what are you setting the max heap to on startup? You might simply not have allowed enough heap for your app to run.

Comment: Show us some context around Sql.java:118.

Comment: Axtually I just tried it in a MySQL tool and it seems to return the square amount of what I want it to, for example instead of 2 it returns 4 or instead of 3 it returns 9, instead of 4 it returns 16 etc.

Comment: I am not setting any max heap on startup just the default, but is there something wrong with my MySQL ?

Comment: did you try running query in mysql query browser

Comment: Yeah I tried running in MySQL command prompt and got the MySQL returns the square amount of what I need.

Comment: Do you run your code once or often (eg server responding to requests and fetching some data)? I can imagine that letting JDBC resources open would result in nasty exceptions. Do you close statement, result set and connection?

Comment: No I don't run the code that often and I do close the connections in a final block, this error only occurs when I put the same data twice into the MySQL, not that I have to put the data in twice, just interested why this error occurs when I do.

Comment: The 'exact error' indicates this a bug in `stl.Sql.printPersonsOrders` and not MySQL. To speak with @MarkusMalkusch : show us some context around Sql.java:118.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your [`rs.absolute(index)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#absolute%28int%29) moves the cursor back (to row 1) and the `while(rs.next())` loop never ends. This is no problem for results sets with one row, as the result set offset is 1.